# Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'cli' does not exist in type TypeOrmModuleOptions

Tags: command-line-interface, nestjs, typeorm

I'm trying to set up migrations in my Nest JS project along with the cli, but no matter what I do, typeorm always swears on the cli.
It's been many days and I'm stumped.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ljs3o.png)

error TS2322: Type '{ type: "postgres"; host: string; port: number; username: string; database: string; password: string; entities: string[]; migrations: string[]; cli: { migrationsDir: string; }; extra: { charset: string; }; synchronize: false; logging: true; }' is not assignable to type 'TypeOrmModuleOptions'.
Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'cli' does not exist in type '{ retryAttempts?: number; retryDelay?: number; toRetry?: (err: any) => boolean; autoLoadEntities?: boolean; keepConnectionAlive?: boolean; verboseRetryLog?: boolean; } & Partial'.

Answer (score 0):

If you use typeorm 0.3.x, typeorm-cli needs migration path as a command option now. You can delete that part typescript complains and check this thread. [TypeORM/nest - running migrations with `useFactory`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72721207/typeorm-nest-running-migrations-with-usefactory)

Answer (score 0):

1. You ORM config should be instance of DataSource
   ormconfig.ts file
   like this:

   export default new DataSource({
   type: 'postgres',
   host: process.env.POSTGRES_HOST
   port: +process.env.POSTGRES_PORT,
   username: process.env.POSTGRES_USER,
   password: process.env.POSTGRES_DB_PASSWORD,
   database: process.env.POSTGRES_DATABASE,
   entities: [__dirname + '/**/*.entity{.ts,.js}'],
   synchronize: false,
   migrations: [__dirname + '/migrations/**/*{.ts,.js}'],
   });

add to package.json next commands:

```
"typeorm": "ts-node -P tsconfig.json ./node_modules/typeorm/cli.js",
"db:drop": "yarn run typeorm schema:drop -d src/ormconfig.ts",
"db:gen": "yarn run typeorm migration:generate src/migrations/migration -d src/ormconfig.ts",
"db:migrate": "yarn run typeorm migration:run -- -d src/ormconfig.ts"
```