# Running migrations with `useFactory`

Tags: typeorm, nest

I have the app in `nestjs` with the `app.module.ts` containing the following configuration:

```js
import { ConfigModule, ConfigService } from '@nestjs/config';
import {
  TypeOrmModuleAsyncOptions,
  TypeOrmModuleOptions,
} from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { DataSource } from 'typeorm';  

export const typeOrmAsyncConfig: TypeOrmModuleAsyncOptions = {
  imports: [ConfigModule],
  inject: [ConfigService],
  name: 'nameA',
  useFactory: (configService: ConfigService) => ({
    type: 'postgres',
    host: configService.get('DB_HOST'),
    port: parseInt(configService.get('DB_PORT') || '5432'),
    username: configService.get('DB_USER'),
    password: configService.get('DB_PASSWORD'),
    database: configService.get('DB_NAME'),
    entities: [__dirname + './../**/*.entity{.ts,.js}'],
    migrations: [__dirname + '/../database/migrations/*{.ts,.js}'],
    synchronize: false,
    cli: {
      entitiesDir: __dirname + './../**/*.entity{.ts,.js}',
    },
    ssl: configService.get('DB_SSL') === 'true',
  }),
};

@Module({
  imports: [
    ConfigModule.forRoot({ isGlobal: true }),
    TypeOrmModule.forRootAsync(typeOrmAsyncConfig),
  ],
  controllers: [AppController],
  providers: [AppService],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

I have `typeorm` installed globally and have migration files generated in the specified paths above, but, I get a `dataSource` not found error.

`typeorm migration:run` output:

```
Runs all pending migrations.

Options:
  -h, --help         Show help                                         [boolean]
  -d, --dataSource   Path to the file where your DataSource instance is defined.
                                                                      [required]
  -t, --transaction  Indicates if transaction should be used or not for
                     migration run. Enabled by default.     [default: "default"]
  -v, --version      Show version number                               [boolean]

Missing required argument: dataSource
```

How do I export a datasource when I'm using the `useFactory` inside of the `app.module.ts` and solve this issue?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since typeorm 0.3.x cli needs a datasource and ormconfig.json is no more supported. Also cli commands have changed too.
You can define separate configurations for nestjs and typeorm-cli.

`src/config/database-config.ts`

```js
    import 'dotenv/config';
    import { DataSourceOptions } from 'typeorm';
    
    const databaseConfig: DataSourceOptions = {
      name: 'default',
      type: 'better-sqlite3',
      database: process.env.DB_NAME,
      entities: [__dirname + '/../entities/*.entity.ts'],
      migrations: [__dirname + '/../migrations/*{.ts,.js}'],
      synchronize: false,
      logging: true,
      migrationsRun: true
    };
    
    export default databaseConfig;
```

then for typeorm cli

`src/config/data-source.ts`

```js
    import { DataSource } from 'typeorm';
    import databaseConfig from './database-config';
    
    export const AppDataSource = new DataSource(databaseConfig);
```

and for nestjs app-module

`src/config/typeorm-config.ts`
`like so: TypeOrmModule.forRootAsync(typeOrmAsyncConfig)`

```js
    import { ConfigModule, ConfigService } from '@nestjs/config';
    import {
      TypeOrmModuleAsyncOptions,
      TypeOrmModuleOptions,
    } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
    import databaseConfig from './database-config';
    
    export const typeOrmConfig: TypeOrmModuleOptions = databaseConfig;
    
    export const typeOrmAsyncConfig: TypeOrmModuleAsyncOptions = {
      imports: [ConfigModule],
      inject: [ConfigService],
      useFactory: async (): Promise<TypeOrmModuleOptions> => {
        return databaseConfig;
      },
    };
```

package.json scripts (change yarn run if needed)

```json
    {
    "typeorm:cli": "ts-node -r tsconfig-paths/register ./node_modules/typeorm/cli -d src/config/data-source.ts",
    "migration:generate": "yarn run typeorm:cli migration:generate",
    "migration:create": "yarn run typeorm:cli migration:create",
    "migration:run": "yarn run typeorm:cli migration:run",
    "migration:revert": "yarn run typeorm:cli migration:revert"
    }
```

for example if you need to generate a new migration complete path needed
in terminal

```
yarn run migration:generate src/migrations/newMigrationName
```

Comment: my question is why are we using ts-node to run the migrations ? Usually ts-node is a dev-dependency

Comment: typeorm-cli itself has 3 binaries as typeorm, typeorm-ts-node-commonjs, typeorm-ts-node-esm. For some reason it is the only way I managed to make it work. I would be happy to learn alternative too.

Comment: I actually had tried creating the datasource as above, but then it errored saying that it was not initialized

Comment: @juztcode you mean cli right? I have just confirmed this way works. make sure datasource export same way and same name.
export const AppDataSource = new DataSource(databaseConfig);

Comment: hm... it seems to work after I added the glob pattern: `migrations: ['./**/*.migration.js']`

Comment: I've mentioned an approach for up migrations , yet a suitable place to manually trigger down is somewhat tricky

Comment: @juztcode both glob pattern or importing Entity Classes work fine. but they will disable the glob pattern in the next version.

Comment: not to bother you, but, I wonder if you know something about this as well: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72778191/typeorm-default-is-being-inserted-while-giving-value-to-the-specified-entity

Comment: hello, question does anyone of you having issue when trying to access env variables? I'm getting undefined even those I import `dotenv/config` just like on the answer.

Comment: @aRtoo check your env file. Dotenv looks for ".env" file in the root directory. If you want to put it in another place, for example:  import * as dotenv from 'dotenv'; dotenv.config({ path: __dirname + '/../../myenv.env' });

Comment: @linusw that's what I thought. I changed my env file name from ".development.env" to  ".env" and it worked and downloaded the dotenv package. but I'm confused because nest already using dotenv. I don't want to download or duplicate it.

Comment: @aRtoo yes nestjs depends on dotenv so you don't need to redownload. If you use npm or yarn, dotenv is already available to import. pnpm needs "pnpm add dotenv" command but doesn't download just creates link to the previous download.

Answer (score 0):

For migration up there seems to be a convenient way, but, since the answer is partial, I'm not marking it done:

```js
   {
     imports: [ConfigModule],
     inject: [ConfigService],
     useFactory: (configService: ConfigService) => ({
       type: 'postgres',
       host: configService.get('DB_HOST'),
       port: parseInt(configService.get('DB_PORT') || '4432'),
       username: configService.get('DB_USER'),
       password: configService.get('DB_PASSWORD'),
       database: configService.get('DB_NAME'),
       entities: [MyEntity],
       migrations: ['./**/*.migration.js'],
       synchronize: false,
       ssl: configService.get('DB_SSL') === 'true',
     }),
     dataSourceFactory: async (options: DataSourceOptions) => {
       const dataSource = await new DataSource(options).initialize();
       await dataSource.runMigrations();
   
       return dataSource;
     },
   }
```

If new migrations are added, they should be applied since the server is restarted.

Comment: this is the equivalent of migrationsRun: true, I had deleted it temporarily in my config. Edited now. Good catch. Although some could prefer "synchronize:true" while developing too. and my code works without defining dataSourceFactory property or initializing manually.

Comment: hm... this is but different than `synchronize:true` though as it should probably run only when you'd merge in the migrations file into the deployed branch

Comment: yes, I am not saying it is a drop in alternative.  I assume developer would know what to modify my code to their needs. My solution is just intended as to make the new cli work in the absence of global ormconfig

Comment: @linusw , do you know if we can use the entity itself for migration?

Comment: I don't know what exactly you mean by "entity itself" only way I know is you can pass entity class to queryRunner.manager in migration files.

Comment: @linusw , do you happen to have a link or sth to an example that does that?

Comment: https://medium.com/@emfelipe/using-typeorm-migrations-for-simple-database-seeding-nestjs-example-1f1acbc0ef24 it is outdated but queryrunner api still works like in this link. I use this method to seed database. Basically create another migrations folder as "seeds".  put it in a datasource configuration as migrations. You should check queryRunner.manager (EntityManager) api documentation too. https://typeorm.io/entity-manager-api

Comment: I did try out the EntityManager api , with something like this: `queryRunner.manager.create(<MY_ENTITY>)` yet it throws error saying no metadata, it doesn't seem like we can create the whole table in postgres with just the entity defined in nest

Comment: apparently you haven't read the whole queryrunner documentation. creating and altering tables done through either generated migrations or functions like queryRunner.createTable, queryRunner.addColumn. queryRunner.manager shines best at inserting or bulk inserting. 
https://typeorm.io/migrations#using-migration-api-to-write-migrations
I don't know what editor you use but I suggest something you can use LSP server-typescript addon. VS Code or Sublime Text. Typeorm already have documentation in the source code you can read by just hovering on code this way.

Comment: by the way metadata error can be result of wrong entities configuration in the datasource. You can try importing Entity Classes and put in the array if you haven't done already.