# typeorm - DEFAULT is being inserted while giving value to the specified entity

Tags: node.js, typeorm

I'm using the migration workaround to seed my database in typeorm, and have got a foreign key, that I'm trying to link to the database, yet, it tells me that foreign key constrained is violated and even though I have provided the value, the error log mentions that i'm inserting null.

The entity is:

```
@Entity('schedule')
export class Schedule extends BaseEntity {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  schedule_id: number;


  @ManyToOne(() => XClass, (xclass) => xclass.schedules, {
    onDelete: 'CASCADE',
    onUpdate: 'CASCADE',
  })
  @JoinColumn({ name: 'x_id' })
  xclass: XClass;
}
```

The data I insert is:

```
const xData = [
  {

    x_id: 1,
  },
  {

    x_id: 2,
  },
  {

    x_id: 3,
  },
  {

    x_id: 4,
  }
];
```

The data is inserted via:

```
export class Schedule1656318288443 implements MigrationInterface {
  public async up(queryRunner: QueryRunner): Promise<void> {
    await queryRunner.manager
      .createQueryBuilder(queryRunner)
      .insert()
      .into(Schedule)
      .values(xData)
      .execute();
  }

  public async down(queryRunner: QueryRunner): Promise<void> {
    return;
  }
}
```

Using a configuration like this:

```
const ormconfig: DataSourceOptions = {
      type: 'postgres',
      host: process.env.DB_HOST,
      port: Number(process.env.DB_PORT),
      username: process.env.DB_USER,
      password: process.env.DB_PASSWORD,
      database: process.env.DB_NAME,
      migrations: ['./**/*.seed.js'], // I run seed on compiled files
    };

    const appDataSource = new DataSource(ormconfig);  
    await appDataSource.initialize();
    await appDataSource.runMigrations();
```

The error log:

```
Migration "schedule1656318288443" failed, error: null value in column "x_id" of relation "schedule" violates not-null constraint
QueryFailedError: null value in column "x_id" of relation "schedule" violates not-null constraint
    at PostgresQueryRunner.query (mypath/node_modules/typeorm/driver/postgres/PostgresQueryRunner.js:211:19)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)
    at async InsertQueryBuilder.execute (mypath/node_modules/typeorm/query-builder/InsertQueryBuilder.js:106:33)
    at async schedule1656318288443.up (mypath/dist/database/seeds/1656318288443-schedule.seed.js:8:9)
    at async MigrationExecutor.executePendingMigrations (mypath/node_modules/typeorm/migration/MigrationExecutor.js:178:17)
    at async DataSource.runMigrations (mypath/node_modules/typeorm/data-source/DataSource.js:248:35)
    at async seed (mypath/dist/utils/seed.util.js:38:9)
    at async exec (mypath/dist/utils/seed.util.js:51:13) {
  query: 'INSERT INTO "schedule"("x_id") VALUES (DEFAULT) RETURNING "schedule_id"',
```

NOTE: I've checked the values of the rows with the primary keys for X exist in the database

Comment: can you verbally explain what you are trying to insert. Looks like you are trying to insert 4 schedule into 4 separate xclass connecting through foreign key for each one. But your query code doesn't do anything to establish relation.

Comment: @linusw , it seems I switched schedule for xclass whilst editing , I've updated the question. I'm trying to insert a bunch of foreign keys into schedule, yet I get the error above if I don't provide an explicit primary key, and If I do so in postgres, the SERIAL property in the database that autogenerates new Id dismantles

Comment: In the error log, it runs the `schedule1656318288443` migration. You have shown migration number `Schedule1656317910541 `.  So, what is the code in the `schedule1656318288443` migration?

Comment: @NairiAbgaryan , it runs the up function in the above Schedule class implementing the migration interface.

Answer (score 1):

Best to my knowledge, typeorm entities can't use foreign key columns same as the ones as decorated @Column(). I would be happy to learn if someone knows better leaves an answer.I don't know any other way than looping in this scenario.

```
  public async up(queryRunner: QueryRunner): Promise<void> {
    for (const x of xData) {
      const xEntityInstance = await queryRunner.manager.findOneBy(XClass, { id: x.x_id });
      await queryRunner.manager.insert(Schedule, { xclass: xEntityInstance });
    }
  }

  public async down(queryRunner: QueryRunner): Promise<void> {
    await queryRunner.manager.clear(Schedule);
  }
```